# Owl carousel - vertical align bottom

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Hi I saw this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJAHL from this post: [owl carousel, navigation center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904146/owl-carousel-navigation-center)

I need to set the items at the bottom of the carousel.

I tried

```
div.owl-item > div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just came across this question and thought I would answer it!

```
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper {
  display: table !important;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Here is the updated [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/amir5000/pen/NPaMNX)